# How to Change Radio Button Label Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

I have exhaustively search the net for answers and have not found a single working solution as of yet. I have written numerous ways in attempt to change the label of a particular radio button.

I am trying to edit the default "Specify your own value:" to a custom text using the Script Editor in SharePoint 2013.

Here is the default code that SharePoint generates for you to give you an idea:
[Snippet Of Code from using F12 on IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84PGE.png)

I am able to access it through CSS as so to test that the element indeed can be changed.

```
<style type="text/css">
span.ms-RadioText label[for="Number_x0020__x0028_Or_x0020_Ran_e6c9be8f-bccc-474a-8b0a-e9a136acbca7_$RadioButtonChoiceFieldFillInRadio"]{
// do whatever
}
</style>
```

Trying to access it through jQuery I have had no success.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
     $("label[for='Number_x0020__x0028_Or_x0020_Ran_e6c9be8f-bccc-474a-8b0a-e9a136acbca7_$RadioButtonChoiceFieldFillInRadio']").attr('.label', 'Assign #');
});
</script>
```

Please help or point out what I am doing wrong!

EDIT: I have tried numerous ways using the .text and .html with no avail from before.

.text("Assign #"); and .html("Assign #"); Changed nothing on SharepPoint.

Comment: can you put it in a fiddle so people can experiment?

Comment: You are trying to set the HTML attribute ".label" which does not exist. As @akshay-prabhakar points out in his answer you need to change the HTML content of the `<label>` element.

Comment: I tried the html content as well and it does not update. I have read from several articles that people have not been able to go around this issue but those posts are also pretty old. I have tried that whole thing.text("Assign #") and .html("Assign #") and it did not change

Comment: @jinglesthula, For some reason it does not compile on fiddle as I have tried before posting here. Since the code is only a snippet of the whole page, it would not work anyway.

Comment: I understand.  Still, it may be worth the effort of getting a minimal fiddle working that demonstrates the bug.  Sometimes the process of removing everything but the problem code reveals the cause of the issue along the way.

Comment: @jinglesthula

https://jsfiddle.net/eq5ybc74/2/

This is what it currently looks like without any scripting.

I want it to say this when using jquery as I can not directly change the html code using the web editor. Unless there is a way I am completely missing, I am at a stand still on this one.

https://jsfiddle.net/eq5ybc74/3/

The javascript code I added didnt do anything

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eq5ybc74/5/

Adding garbage characters before the radio button

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

HTML:

```
<div id="TheOptions">
  <input type="radio" id="test1" name="mylist"/><label for="test1">option 1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="test2" name="mylist"/><label for="test1">option 2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="test3" name="mylist"/><label for="test1">option 3</label>
  <input type="radio" id="test4" name="mylist"/><label for="test1">option 4</label>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('label[for=test1]').html('best option');
```

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle experiment how you need this.

Comment: I posted the original, what I want, and what it added using jquery above in the comments.

Comment: Can you please share the link how you are checking ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eq5ybc74/5/

This link shows what I WANT it to do in Jquery with the html already set. As you can see, its outputting garbage in front of the radio button (That does not show up on sharepoint at all, it just does nothing) I don't know if my syntax is wrong or what.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('label[for=Number_x0020__x0028_Or_x0020_Ran_e6c9be8f-bccc-474a-8b0a-e9a136acbca7_$RadioButtonChoiceFieldFillInRadio]')
  .html('new label');
```